# Removing stubborn programs from menu bar in macOS

Tags: macos

My institution-provided M1 macOS Sonoma machine has several programs controlled by their profile. Many of these programs generate a very irritating (to me, at least) icon in the menu extras in the top right. I was able to remove many of these icons by deleting these programs' respective launch agents in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`, `/Library/LaunchAgents/`, or `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` from the terminal using `sudo rm -rf <launch agent>`.

One of these icons, however, has defeated me. NewPrivilegeManagement does not appear to have any launch agents to delete, and I cannot delete its files under `/Applications/`—when I try to do so using `sudo rm`, I get `rm: Cannot remove <file>: Operation not permitted`. I have tried disabling `csrutil` from Recovery OS, and I still could not delete the files. Perhaps this is because the application is running, but I also cannot kill the process from Activity Monitor.

To be clear, deleting the program from my machine is not my immediate goal—any FOSS solution which removes it from the menu bar *cleanly* will suffice. I have tried some applications which modify the behaviour of the toolbar, however they do not seem to be maintained and are fairly buggy on modern versions of macOS. I do not care if the solution violates my institution's cyber security code of conduct.

Comment: For reference, in case this helps your search terms, the proper name for the bar is the menu bar, and the icon menus on the right hand side are called "Menu Extras".

Comment: @Spiff thanks for the correction—I have edited my question. I did actually use the search term "menu bar" when looking for solutions, I think my brain just substituted a term I was more familiar with when I was writing the question. Didn't know about "Menu Extras" though, that is useful information.

Comment: Does your Org manage the computer in some way? Have you contacted their IT support staff regarding this issue?

Comment: @music2myear yes, they do, yes, I have, and no, they were no help. My organisation does not develop these programs themselves, they pay for licenses for these programs and therefore they cannot add options to these programs to disable menu extras icons. And they are hardly inclined to help me remove such programs when they are the ones who insist they be installed. As I stated in the question, I am not concerned that they do not want me to remove these programs.